# How do I find out the elements before a particular element in XML in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an XML in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE repub SYSTEM "C:\repub\Repub_V1.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="C:\repub\repub.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<repubold>
    <head>
        <title>xxx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <sec>
            <title>First Title</title>
            <break name="1-1"/>
            <pps>This is an invalid text.</pps>
            <h1>
                <page num="1"/>First Heading
            </h1>
            <bl>This is another text</bl>
            <fig>
                <img src="images/img_1-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <fc>This is a caption</fc>
            </fig>
            <p>
                <bold>This</bold> again
                <br/> is
                <br/>
                <bold> a 
                    <br/>paragraph
                </bold>
            </p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
            <title>Second Title</title>
            <break name="2-1"/>
            <h1>
                <page num="1"/>Second Heading
            </h1>
            <bl>This is another text</bl>
            <fig>
                <img src="images/img_2-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <fc>This is a caption</fc>
                <cr>This is a credit</cr>
            </fig>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
            <title>First Title</title>
            <break name="3-1"/>
            <h1>
                <page num="1"/>Third Heading
            </h1>
            <bl>This is another text</bl>
            <fig>
                <img src="images/img_3-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <fc>This is a caption</fc>
            </fig>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
            <title>Third Title</title>
            <break name="4-1"/>
            <h1>
                <page num="1"/>Fourth Heading
            </h1>
            <bl>This is another text</bl>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            <fig>
                <img src="images/img_4-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <fc>This is a caption</fc>
                <cr>This is a credit</cr>
            </fig>
            <break name="5-1"/>
            <h1>
                <page num="1"/>Fifth Heading
            </h1>
            <bl>This is another text</bl>
            <fig>
                <img src="images/img_5-1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <fc>This is a caption</fc>
                <cr>This is a credit</cr>
            </fig>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </sec>
    </body>
</repubold>
```

In this, all the `<break>` tags are followed by `<h1>`. So, I want to check the elements before `<h1>`, if any. If it is not `<psf>` then it will show an error.
Because I want that `<psf>` is the only acceptable tag between `<break>` and `<h1>`. It can be `<psf>` or nothing, but if there is any other `<xyz>` tag, then it will show an error.

Please help.

I have tried this, but the code is not working:

```
var pagetag = xdoc.Descendants("break").Descendants("h1")
.Where(br => br.ElementsBeforeSelf("h1") != new XElement("psf") ||                                                                 
br.ElementsBeforeSelf("h1") != new XElement("break"))
.Select(br => br.Attribute("name").Value.Trim())
.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);

MessageBox.Show("The following articles have invalid tags before <h1>: " + pagetag);
```

Comment: What is it that's not working exactly?

Comment: @Stefan - I have updated the code. The output should have been 1-1 but I am getting an exception `Sequence has no elements`.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do - your sample XML doesn't have *any* psf elements, which makes it harder to understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Basically, in general, there should be no elements after `<break>` and before `<h1>`. But, the only exception I can have is `<psf>`. If there are any other elements present after `<break>` and before `<h1>` then it will be an error. So, in my input, `<break name="1-1">` is an error as it contains an element between `<break>` and `<h1>` and it is not `<psf>`.

Comment: I've added an answer, but it would be useful for your XML to include an example of that. Currently there's a lot in the XML document that isn't particularly relevant, but it doesn't have an example of everything that *is* relevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes, I executed your given code and it works just like I wanted. I have tested it on 4 files as of now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that `ElementsBeforeSelf()` returns a *sequence* of elements, but you're checking whether that sequence is equal to a single `XElement` - and comparing them by reference using `!=`.

You're also asking for the descendants of `break` elements - and there aren't any. I think you just want all the `h1` elements.

To clarify your requirement, I *think* you're trying to find all the `h1` elements, where the last sibling element before the `h1` is neither `break` nor `psf`. For each of those elements, you want to find the latest `break` element before the `h1` (if there is one) and report the `name` attribute.

Assuming that's the case, here's some code which I believe does what you want, with comments explaining it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XName brName = "break";
        XName psfName = "psf";

        var invalidNames = 
            from h1 in xdoc.Descendants("h1")
            // Find the last sibling element before the h1
            let previous = h1.ElementsBeforeSelf().LastOrDefault()
            // It's invalid if there isn't a previous element, or it has
            // a name other than break or psf
            where previous?.Name != brName && previous?.Name != psfName
            // Get the name to report, handling the case where there's
            // no previous break or no "name" attribute
            select ((string) h1.ElementsBeforeSelf(brName).LastOrDefault()?.Attribute("name")) ?? "(no named break)";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", invalidNames));
    }
}
```

It has a bit of a flaw, in that if an `<h1>` is invalid, but has no *immediate* `<break>` predecessor, it will look back as far as the earlier one to find a name... so if you remove the `<break name="5-1"/>` element for example, it'll report the name of "4-1" as being invalid, as that's the last `break` element before the `h1` that *was* after 5-1. I don't know how important that is to you.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your comment and given my code. Your code started showing all the `<break>` tags in the XML and that is not required. Please go through the comment and help me out.

Comment: @PrimoChalice: You shouldn't edit answers to effectively request clarification. My answer addresses the question you asked - if there's more that you hadn't specified, please ask a new question. You can leave a comment here referring to the new question.